# Flare3D FlashBuilder Mobile Error

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder4.5, flare3d

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flare.basic.Scene3D;
    import flare.basic.Viewer3D;
    import flare.core.Pivot3D;

    import flare.basic.Scene3D;
    import flare.basic.Viewer3D;
    import flare.core.Pivot3D;

    [SWF(frameRate = 60, width = 800, height = 450, backgroundColor = 0x000000)]

    /**
     * Starting the project.
     */
    public class MyFirstApp extends Sprite 
    {
        private var scene:Scene3D;
        private var planet:Pivot3D;
        private var astronaut:Pivot3D;

        public function MyFirstApp() 
        {

            trace("Hello Flare3D");

        }



    }

}
```

I am trying to get Flare3D to work in an ActionScript Mobile Project in Flash Builder.When I run the project I am recieving an error message that says ... " VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::ByteArrayAsset could not be found. " All I have in this code is three Vairables, I have removed all other code and still I recieve this message. I have added Flare3D into the ActionScript BulderPath. My Goal is to take the Yellow Planet Tutorial and run it on iOS Air Simulator. http://www.flare3d.com/demos/yellowplanet/.... If I dont include the 3 variables I get the trace statement to execute with no error message. How does adding three variable cause this error, or rather what am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed error mx.core::ByteArrayAsset by adding the Flex SDK into my Actionscript Mobile project.  By using Scene3D this must be linked to the project.